# How to add options and conditionals using swipe events on a list element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple unordered list with li elements. I would like to do something similar to the [rc-swipeout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-swipeout) npm library where if you swipe on a list element you are presented with options.

Unfortunately I am running Meteor/Blaze application and unable to use React. I have found a couple of libraries that are simple jQuery such as [swipeTo](https://github.com/Ipno84/swipeTo) which has a [demo here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-iOS-like-Swipe-To-Delete-swipeTo/) (works on mobile).

The swipeTo library actually provides some swipe functionality, it gives options when you swipe over.

However, I would like to add functionality where when I swipe all the way, the list item is deleted. Right now when you swipe all the way, the list item just rebounds back to its regular position as you can see in that demo.

What is the best method to add a conditional such as this?

Comment: In the demo, I'm seeing that a short swipe to the left presents the option to delete the item, or cancel the delete.  Are you looking for a way to listen to the touch coordinates and automatically delete?

Comment: So if they do a short swipe (i.e. 200px) it presents those two options, which is what the library does now.

What I would like to add is functionality when I do a long swipe, like to the edge of the screen, the item automatically deletes as the default action instead of rebounding back to it's origin where it presents those two options.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking `event.clientX`; save the value in swipeStart and compare it to the value in swipeEnd. 
(I couldn't figure out how the swipeTo.js script made event coordinates available, so I edited it, lines 40 and 93):

```
if(typeof swipeStart == 'function') {
    swipeStart.call(this, start);   //add 'start' as parameter
}

if(typeof swipeEnd== 'function') {
    swipeEnd.call(this, absMoveStatus, e.changedTouches[0].clientX);   //add amount moved and clientX as parameter
}
```

In your main script:

```
$(function() {
    $('.item-swipe').swipeTo({
        minSwipe: 100,
        angle: 10,
        binder: true,
        swipeStart: function(start) { //now use start value
            console.log('start', start); 
        },
        swipeMove: function(e) {
            console.log('move');
        },
        swipeEnd: function(movedAmount, end) {
            console.log('end', movedAmount, end);
            // if movedAmount value > 200, and end value < 20 (close to left side), 
            // then delete the item
        },
    }); 
    deleteItem();
})
```